# While Loop Terminating after ResultSet.execute

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, while-loop, executequery

I am trying to make TABLE COMPB equivalent to TABLE COMPA by Update and Delete operations on Table COMPB based on Table COMPA. The code works perfectly fine while generating proper SQL. Problem is, the moment I put execute statement as below, while loop terminates in first iteration itself. Not able to understand this behavior of ResultSet in java. Any help here? Where I am going wrong?

```
//Comparision between Minus Table(seta) and COMPB (setc)
        //ID Contains Primary Key of COMPB Table
        ResultSet seta=stmt.executeQuery("select * from COMPA minus select * from COMPB");


        while(seta.next())
        { 
            String insert="";
            String update="";
            boolean contains=ArrayUtils.contains(ID, seta.getInt(1));

            if (contains==true)
             { 
                update="Update COMPB SET COMPB.EMPNAME='"+seta.getString(2)+"',COMPB.EMAILID='"+seta.getString(3)+"' where "+seta.getInt(1)+"=COMPB.EMPID";
                stmt.executeUpdate(update);
                System.out.println(update);
             }
            else 
             {
            insert="Insert INTO COMPB values ("+seta.getInt(1)+" , '"+seta.getString(2)+"' , '"+seta.getString(3)+"')";
              stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
              System.out.println(insert);
             }  


        }
```

Comment: I imagine it doesn't like you reusing `stmt` for the subsequent `executeUpdate()` calls, but what debugging have you done? What does the initial query get if you run it manually - assuming all changes in all sessions are committed? Also, why use loops instead of a single merge statement; and if you must use loops, why aren't you using prepared statements and bind variables?

Comment: Thanks Alex. Reuse of stmt within a loop was the issue. I am yet to understand how can it break the while loop. But for now I corrected it.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you stop concatenating values into a query string, use a prepared statement with parameter placeholders instead. Your current code is not safe and vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel & all:Thanks for all the experienced suggestions and spending time to go through my small query, in spite of your busy schedule. Motivates me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There can be two possible reasons for this:

- Re-use of same `stmt` object : Result set object is mapped to statement that returned it (via `executeQuery` method), and re-using the same statement object in the middle of iteration will make resultset invalid. You should create a new statement object and execute those queries with it.
- Using `CONCUR_READ_ONLY` `resultSet` (default) : [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)  Oracle's documentation on result set. By default, it is not modifiable. You may need to use `CONCUR_UPDATABLE` resultset if records need modifying. [Here](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-updatable-resultset-in-jdbc/179) is an example of that.

Answer (score 1):

> Not able to understand this behavior of ResultSet in java.

You use the same  `PreparedStatement` `stmt` instance to perform the update :

```
ResultSet seta=stmt.executeQuery("select * from COMPA minus select * from COMPB");

while(seta.next()){ 
    ...

   update="Update COMPB SET COMPB.EMPNAME='"+seta.getString(2)+"',COMPB.EMAILID='"+seta.getString(3)+"'    where "+seta.getInt(1)+"=COMPB.EMPID";
   stmt.executeUpdate(update);
   System.out.println(update);
   ...
  }
```

Your `ResultSet seta` comes from `PreparedStatement` `stmt` instance.
So I suppose that invoking another execute method on a `PreparedStatement` instance has side-effect on previously ResultSet object returned by the `PreparedStatement` instance.

You should create a new instance of `PreparedStatement` to execute your other queries.

Comment: The code shown uses a normal `Statement` object, but the gist of your answer is right.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  Indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @Hari Prasad You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestions below, I changed the loop by creating preparedstatement objects.

```
         while(seta.next())
        { 

            boolean contains=ArrayUtils.contains(ID, seta.getInt(1));

            if (contains==true)
             { 


                PreparedStatement update_stmt =con.prepareStatement("Update COMPB SET COMPB.EMPNAME=?,COMPB.EMAILID=? where COMPB.EMPID=?");
                update_stmt.setInt(3,seta.getInt(1));
                update_stmt.setString(1,seta.getString(2));
                update_stmt.setString(2,seta.getString(3));
                int k=update_stmt.executeUpdate();  
                System.out.println(k+" records updated");

             }
            else 
             {

            PreparedStatement insert_stmt =con.prepareStatement("insert into COMPB values(?,?,?)");
            insert_stmt.setInt(1,seta.getInt(1));
            insert_stmt.setString(2,seta.getString(2));
            insert_stmt.setString(3,seta.getString(3));
            int k=insert_stmt.executeUpdate();  
            System.out.println(k+" records inserted"); 

             }  


        }
```